# Roku How to get standard input in Main.brs

Tags: input, scanf, roku, brightscript

I am writing a Roku application and I need to read a string from the standard input. I am aware that to print to the standard output I can use the function `print`, but I need to give to the user the launches the script the possibility to insert new parameters at run time, for example (pseudo-code):

```
print "Enter server IP: "
string ip = getline();
print "Server IP " + ip
```

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: What do you mean by reading from standard input? Channels are not launched by the command line.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to add Keyboad*** component to your Scene.xml file:

```
<Keyboard
    id = "keyboard" 
/>
```

After that add a Button component in Scene.xml, declare it in Scene.brs - init() function and set observer field on "buttonSelected".Also declare keyboard and set focus on it:

init() :

```
m.keyboard = m.top.findNode("keyboard")
m.keyboard.setFocus(true)
m.button = m.top.findNode("button")
m.button.observeField("buttonSelected","onButtonSelected")
```

Then create a Sub to get a user input from Keyboard when button is pressed:

```
Sub onButtonSelected()
    print m.keyboard.textEditBox.text
End Sub
```

***Note that Keyboard component has TextEditBox build in so you don't have to add it manually in Scene.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "standard input" concept in Roku development. There are a few way your code can take external input though.

One is as mentioned above by @U-Mitic - to use component with keyboard input from the remote control, like `roKeyboardScreen` or `KeyboardDialog` RSG node and the like.

Another is to send such information externally over http by using ECP (Roku's External Control Protocol) -  either /input or /launch w/params